# Angularjs Validate form on field change using external variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a `form` where a user can add multiple credit card information, similar to this one:

```
<form name="newCard">
    <label for="surname">Card number: </label> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="formCard.code" required name="code" />

    <label for="surname">CVV: </label> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="formCard.cvv" required name="cvv" />

    <input type="button" value="Add Card" />
    <input type="button" value="Save" />
</form>
```

The "Add card" `button` adds the validated current card data to a `js` array in my controller.

I would like the "Save" `button` to be disabled unless this array is populated. How can I use custom validation in Angular to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your array to the scope. Then :

```
<input type="button" value="Add Card" ng-disabled="!yourJsArray.length" />
```